How do i get all the values in a JSON array?
I am a new node js programmer, so help is much appreciated, I am trying to log all the buyer_sku_code but it only logs one of them which is only the "WDP" array
this is the JSON
[
    {
      "product_name": "WDP",
      "brand": "ml",
      "price": 18245,
      "buyer_sku_code": "mlgwdp",
      "buyer_product_status": true,
      "seller_product_status": true,
      "unlimited_stock": true,
      "stock": 0,
      "multi": true,
      "start_cut_off": "23:45",
      "end_cut_off": "00:15",
      "desc": "-"
    },
    
    {
      "product_name": "86 Diamonds",
      "brand": "ml",
      "price": 16135,
      "buyer_sku_code": "mlg86",
      "buyer_product_status": true,
      "seller_product_status": true,
      "unlimited_stock": true,
      "stock": 0,
      "multi": true,
      "start_cut_off": "23:45",
      "end_cut_off": "00:15",
      "desc": "-"
    },
    
    {
      "product_name": "172 Diamonds",
      "brand": "ml",
      "price": 31992,
      "buyer_sku_code": "mlg172",
      "buyer_product_status": true,
      "seller_product_status": true,
      "unlimited_stock": true,
      "stock": 0,
      "multi": true,
      "start_cut_off": "23:45",
      "end_cut_off": "00:15",
      "desc": "-"
    },
    
     {
      "product_name": "257 Diamonds",
      "brand": "ml",
      "price": 47603,
      "buyer_sku_code": "mlg257",
      "buyer_product_status": true,
      "seller_product_status": true,
      "unlimited_stock": true,
      "stock": 0,
      "multi": true,
      "start_cut_off": "23:45",
      "end_cut_off": "00:15",
      "desc": "-"
    },
    
     {
      "product_name": "344 Diamonds",
      "brand": "ml",
      "price": 64969,
      "buyer_sku_code": "mlg344",
      "buyer_product_status": true,
      "seller_product_status": true,
      "unlimited_stock": true,
      "stock": 0,
      "multi": true,
      "start_cut_off": "23:45",
      "end_cut_off": "00:15",
      "desc": "-"
    } 
]


this is what i wrote in the nodejs script
 fs.readFile('./custom-raeonn/digiflazz/prepaidData.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data); 
     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       console.log(data[i].buyer_sku_code);
       if (data[i].buyer_sku_code== kod) {
           conn.reply(m.chat,`Passed`,m)
       } else { return conn.reply(m.chat,`Sorry. Could not find any product code of ${kod},   Perhaps a typo?`,m) }
     }
  });

It logs only one which is "mlgwdp" but not the others
Ive searched everywhere for the answer but none seems to be working. Im not really good at explaining but i am expecting to log all the "buyer_sku_code" codes

As soon as the else block executes, the for loop will not make any other iterations, as you exit it with that return. You cannot know whether you have not found it before you have made all iterations of the for loop, so that else ... return should not be inside your loop.

Do you want to call reply multiple times when you find that code multiple times? Do you really want to log all sku codes even when you have already found the one you are looking for?

Your answer was actually the solution, Thank you! Though i dont know how to mark this question as solved..

As soon as the else block executes, the for loop will not make any other iterations, as you exit it with that return. You cannot know whether you have not found it before you have made all iterations of the for loop, so that else ... return should not be inside your loop.
You could do something like this (with minimal changes):
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].buyer_sku_code);
    if (data[i].buyer_sku_code== kod) {
        conn.reply(m.chat, `Passed`, m);
        return; // You probably want to stop looking further
    }
}
// If we get here, we didn't find it
conn.reply(m.chat, `Sorry. Could not find any product code of ${kod},   Perhaps a typo?`, m);

I would suggest using more modern JavaScript features and use the some array method (without logging this time):
const found = data.some(obj => obj.buyer_sku_code === kod);
const msg = found ? "Passed" : `Sorry. Could not find any product code of ${kod}, perhaps a typo?`;
conn.reply(m.chat, msg, m);


iteration.


let arrOfObjects = [
    {
      "product_name": "WDP",
      "brand": "ml",
      "price": 18245,
      "buyer_sku_code": "mlgwdp",
      "buyer_product_status": true,
      "seller_product_status": true,
      "unlimited_stock": true,
      "stock": 0,
      "multi": true,
      "start_cut_off": "23:45",
      "end_cut_off": "00:15",
      "desc": "-"
    },
    
    {
      "product_name": "86 Diamonds",
      "brand": "ml",
      "price": 16135,
      "buyer_sku_code": "mlg86",
      "buyer_product_status": true,
      "seller_product_status": true,
      "unlimited_stock": true,
      "stock": 0,
      "multi": true,
      "start_cut_off": "23:45",
      "end_cut_off": "00:15",
      "desc": "-"
    } 
]

arrOfObjects.forEach(function(obj){
console.log(obj["buyer_sku_code"])
})



